# Use wordpress for school results?

Tags: plugins

I want to use wordpress as a school results script.

Create a database of students, subjects and results.

And the end-user query a name of an ID to get results & data for specific student.

Is there such a plugin to do so?

Comment: You don't really need a plugin to do this.  Each user can have its own meta data so you can add what you want there and querying it will just be like querying for posts.  WordPress already comes with all API functions to do what you need.

Comment: It's not about the wordpress users & authors, it's about students in school who shouldn't have accounts on the site, just records in the database for results.

Comment: How do you have a student's records without a student in the database??

Comment: I don't want to create login account for each student, students should be stored as something like taxonomies.

Comment: Ok you can achieve that using Custom Post type and a taxonomy of student. Please refer to -> http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types